# I have been getting random BSOD (DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL - Source: nwifi.sys) in the last 3 days

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, bsod

I have been getting random BSOD (DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL - Source: nwifi.sys) in the last 3 days.

They seem to only appear when playing videos on YouTube, but it might be a coincidence.

#### What has changed in the last 3 days?

Nothing on the laptop itself. I plugged in a new keyboard and mouse (both USB), and a USB hub (USB-C).

I also installed new drivers for the Intel Graphics and "Intel(R) Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Manager" as suggested by Dell Driver Updater, but this was an attempt to fix the BSOD, which already happened before updating these drivers.

#### What are the laptop info and specs?

- Text version: https://mega.nz/#!w8AGRbDb!_n4JklD702aj7aoC48b-yawUQ69-cko13R9Zt8X_U6c
- Speccy version (can be imported into Speccy): https://mega.nz/#!YpQhAYCT!NTfqThbNZ-lqDVMTsKqGTDwKc4GCuUTWzipsDuVVE8c
- MsInfo32 Output:  https://mega.nz/#!8p4SwTgR!NXJeUPATjAZ6JUUI4-s_-iJGOcDz1FvRmO8JCSniQs8

#### Most recent dump files?

This is the content of C:\Windows\Minidump: (all 3 are the most recent BSOD dumps and match with the date and time of the BSODs).

- https://mega.nz/#!40B0TBAA!7n_QUccYUPr80FN0bvhY2evT_0SWbadh1MBFpxqh3Hk
- https://mega.nz/#!B0YRUIAZ!XB25NdCVqBFkEleRdFPsKgGssf9PReYKXP5IJIFz1uY
- https://mega.nz/#!FtJQmIba!sYXWqG3ayUyaIp7Vf6wnQrhJMYldHwIg8tw46cNp2fo

#### What have you tried?

I have checked with the Dell System Detect utility to see if all the drivers were up to date; 2 weren't and I updated them (as written above) but that didn't solve the issue.

I have cleaned the system Registry with the CCleaner utility, but that didn't solve the issue.

#### What can I do?

**EDIT**: Upon suggestion, I updated the killer drivers.

All seemes fine of a while, then, after the laptop went to suspended state, I noticed the external mouse stopped working, while the touchpad worked.

After plugging and unplugging, I rebooted.

Laptop stuck to reboot for 6 min (usually takes 6 seconds) then BSOD: DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE.

- **Log**: https://mega.nz/#!RxhhyBYJ!7AGY6uAErZnqeE_lGCfk65Webalfc0vNbC_NokwJ-ys

Comment: Have you tried to remove and reinstall the wifi drivers? The `Source: nwifi.sys` suggests that might be the source of the problem. You could also try to "repair" the system with a Windows 10 DVD.

Comment: All the mega links are gone, and since the question dosen't really organically have any of the information about OP's system, its hard to tell what's going on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Looking at the dmp with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks), shows that the Wifi driver `bwcW10x64.sys` could cause the crash.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (d1)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If kernel debugger is available get stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000decafc37, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
Arg4: fffff80e930ddcec, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for bwcW10x64.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for bwcW10x64.sys

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.14393.953 (rs1_release_inmarket.170303-1614)

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Alienware

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  Alienware 17 R3

SYSTEM_SKU:  Alienware 15 R2

SYSTEM_VERSION:  1.2.14

BIOS_VENDOR:  Alienware

BIOS_VERSION:  1.2.14

BIOS_DATE:  06/02/2016

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Alienware

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  Alienware 17 R3

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  A00

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: decafc37

BUGCHECK_P2: 2

BUGCHECK_P3: 0

BUGCHECK_P4: fffff80e930ddcec

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

FAULTING_IP: 
nwifi!MP6ReturnNBL+30
fffff80e`930ddcec 488b7a28        mov     rdi,qword ptr [rdx+28h]

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: a98

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 5e

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,5e,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 84'00000000 (cache) 84'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  AV

PROCESS_NAME:  System

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
02 nt!KiPageFault
03 nwifi!MP6ReturnNBL
04 ndis!ndisCallReceiveCompleteHandler
05 ndis!ndisInvokeNextReceiveCompleteHandler
06 ndis!NdisFReturnNetBufferLists
07 bwcW10x64
08 0x0
09 0x0
0a 0x0
0b bwcW10x64
0c 0x0
0d 0x0
0e 0x0
0f bwcW10x64


STACK_COMMAND:  kb


0: kd> lmvm bwcW10x64
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
fffff80e`95740000 fffff80e`95aa6000   bwcW10x64 T (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: bwcW10x64.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\bwcW10x64.sys
    Image name: bwcW10x64.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Wed Mar 23 16:46:14 2016 (56F2BA46)
```

So update the Broadcom Wifi driver or connect via LAN cable to the internet router.

The latest dump is shpws that the Audio driver (IntcDAud.sys) causes the issue:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000004, The power transition timed out waiting to synchronize with the Pnp
    subsystem.
Arg2: 000000000000012c, Timeout in seconds.
Arg3: ffff9c09325f8040, The thread currently holding on to the Pnp lock.
Arg4: fffff80187ce2900, nt!TRIAGE_9F_PNP on Win7 and higher

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for IntcDAud.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for IntcDAud.sys
Implicit thread is now ffff9c09`325f8040

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.14393.953 (rs1_release_inmarket.170303-1614)

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Alienware

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  Alienware 17 R3

SYSTEM_SKU:  Alienware 15 R2

SYSTEM_VERSION:  1.2.14

BIOS_VENDOR:  Alienware

BIOS_VERSION:  1.2.14

BIOS_DATE:  06/02/2016

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Alienware

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  Alienware 17 R3

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  A00

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: 4

BUGCHECK_P2: 12c

BUGCHECK_P3: ffff9c09325f8040

BUGCHECK_P4: fffff80187ce2900

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  4

IMAGE_NAME:  HDAudBus.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  57899b7f

MODULE_NAME: HDAudBus

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff806fec70000 HDAudBus

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: a98

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 5e

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,5e,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 84'00000000 (cache) 84'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KiSwapContext
01 nt!KiSwapThread
02 nt!KiCommitThreadWait
03 nt!KeWaitForSingleObject
04 nt!IoReleaseRemoveLockAndWaitEx
05 nt!PopFxUnregisterDevice
06 nt! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'
07 nt!PoFxUnregisterDevice
08 portcls!UnregisterRuntimeManagement
09 portcls!PnpStopDevice
0a portcls!DispatchPnp
0b portcls!PcDispatchIrp
0c IntcDAud
0d 0x0
0e 0x0
```

This Intel HDMI audio driver is from 2016,

```
Loaded symbol image file: IntcDAud.sys
Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\IntcDAud.sys
Image name: IntcDAud.sys
Browse all global symbols  functions  data
Timestamp:        Mon Jun 27 15:35:53 2016
```

so also look for a [driver update](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=Intel%20HD%20530) of your Intel HD 530. The Intel audio driver is bundled to the GPU driver.

Comment: Hi. thanks for your help. Could you please look at the edit? The situation got worse..

Comment: @Athamas you get a new crash, this time the audio driver causes the issues

Comment: I have a sound blaster recon audio card, their last driver is from 2016..

Comment: IntcDAud.sys is the Intel HDMI audio driver. so update the the GPU driver for the Intel HD530: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=Intel+HD+530 Here the driver is from early 2017.

Comment: @Athamas you're welcome :)